# JTable data is invisible unless cell is selected

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm creating a JTable with data contained in 2 Vector, rowData and columnNames. I'm using a renderer to give the colour I want to the JTable. But data is invisible unless I click a cell: then only that cell data is visible.

My code:

```
   // Creating table
    final JTable tablaCurvas = new JTable();
    // Applng colours and column sizes with renderer
    TableCellRenderer tableRender = new TableRenderer();
    tablaCurvas.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, tableRender);
    // Create an easy model to add data to table
    tablaCurvas.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
       public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
           //Only the second column
           return column == 1;
       }

    });
    // Necessary clicks to edit cell
    ((DefaultCellEditor) tablaCurvas.getDefaultEditor(Object.class)).setClickCountToStart(1);
    // Add table into a scrollPane
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tablaCurvas);
    // Fill the pane
    tablaCurvas.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    // Preferred size
    tablaCurvas.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(150,100));
```

And the renderer:

```
class TableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                    JTable table,
                    Object value,
                    boolean isSelected,
                    boolean hasFocus,
                    int row,
                    int column)
    {       
        setEnabled(table == null || table.isEnabled());
        if (column == 0)
            setHorizontalAlignment(LEFT);
        else // (column == 1)
            setHorizontalAlignment(RIGHT);
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
            TableColumn columna = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            if (i==0){
                columna.setPreferredWidth(150);
            }
            if (i==1) columna.setPreferredWidth(50);
        }
        setBackground(table.getBackground());
        setForeground(table.getForeground());
        if (row%2==1) setBackground(java.awt.Color.white);
        else setBackground(new java.awt.Color(211, 217, 255)); 

        return this;
    }
```

Any way, appart from this, I'm finding much more difficult to learn how to use JTables than other Objects, because Oracle Tutorial is not very well explained in that chapter. Any book-chapter or online tutorial for JTables recommended?

Comment: probably unrelated to your problem: do not change any property of the renderer target (nor its dependents) in getXXRendererComponent - that easily results in hard-to-detect loops. Consider all parameters strictly read-only

Comment: maybe the background color is the same as the foreground?

Comment: I don't think background color is the problem, because minutes ago it was visible, when using JTable without a model. When I added a model to make first column non-editable, problem appeared.

Could you explain your first comment more extended? Sounds interesting and I'm always willing to learn

Comment: Roman, you should not be setting the widths of the TableColumn in the renderer. A renderer should only change the properties of itself. @Kleopatra, I'm surprised you let this one slip through :-)

Comment: @camickr - actually, I did tell him not to (or at least tried to, not successfully if even you didn't get it :) - see my first comment

Comment: @kleopatra, Silly me, I missed the comment completely :( I knew that was too easy for you to miss :)

Comment: So, where should I change widths then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the text for the `DefaultTableCellRenderer` component.

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                    Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                    int column) {

    //.... your code

    setText(value != null ? value.toString() : ""); // suppress null values
    return this;
}
```

---

This screenshot was taken with some example data:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Works! But i don't understand why. Data was supposed to be String already, and when I entered that data to the JTable without a model it worked properly. Could you explain what happened here please?

Comment: NOTE: It worked with your previous answer (setText(value.toString());), I didn't need to try out this one after you edited